# percentage calculator crashing when number and percentage windows are empty

Tags: java, android, crash, calculator

When i press Calculate button app just crashes

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (percentageTxt.getText()!=null && numberTxt.getText()!=null){
                float percentege = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
                float dec = percentege / 100;
                float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());
                totalTextWiew.setText(Float.toString(total));
                }else{
                totalTextWiew.setText("Error");
                }
```

Comment: And what does the logcat say?

Comment: Why do you think the app should not crash? Please describe how you think your logic is supposed to work. Also, please try to put the essence of the problem into the title. Your problem seems unrelated to your app being a percentage calculator. A `x`-bottles-of-beer-printer or a inch-to-centimeter converter implemented the same way would experience the same problem. A title that is more to the point would be "Android app crashes when numeric input field is empty". In the same spirit, please try to make your example minimal, i.e. remove lines that don't affect on the observed problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution handles empty strings and invalid input for cases when the inputs do not contain valid floats.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            float percentege = Float.parseFloat(percentageTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = percentege / 100;
            float total = dec * Float.parseFloat(numberTxt.getText().toString());

            totalTextWiew.setText(Float.toString(total));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            totalTextWiew.setText("Error");
        }
    }
```